# How to dynamically change the number of characters to be entered in textbox, based on the length of a database value?

Tags: c#, winforms

E.G. If the `vehicle.VIN` length is 3, show one character and leave the user to enter the remaining 2.

My below code works but I'm wondering is it possible to do this in a much more graceful way? The `vehicle.VIN` minimum length is 3 and the maximum is 22. The max the  user can enter is set to 7.

`this._vinLast7TextBox.MaxLength = 7;`

```
        if (_vinValueLabel.Text.Length == 3)
        {
            _vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - 2);
        }
        else if (_vinValueLabel.Text.Length == 4)
        {
            _vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - 3);
        }
        else if (_vinValueLabel.Text.Length == 5)
        {
            _vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - 4);
        }
        else if (_vinValueLabel.Text.Length == 6)
        {
            _vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - 5);
        }
        else if (_vinValueLabel.Text.Length == 7)
        {
            _vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - 6);
        }
        else
        {
            _vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - 7);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should do the same thing:

```
_vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN;
_vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN.Remove(_vehicle.VIN.Length - Math.Min(7, _vinValueLabel.Text.Length - 1));
```

Comment: I tested this with a 17 length VIN and I got error message **startIndex must be less than length of string**

Comment: `_vehicle.VIN` is 17 characters or `_vinValueLabel.Text` is 17 characters? Does the same VIN work with your current code?

Comment: `_vehicle.VIN` is 17 characters. Yes it does. I have updated my code slightly in the question.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you copied my code correctly? There's no way startIndex could be greater than or equal to the length of _vehicle.VIN in my code if _vehicle.VIN is 17 characters unless _vinValueLabel.Text is empty.

Comment: The issue is that  _vinValueLabel.Text is empty. The line `_vinValueLabel.Text = _vehicle.VIN;` need's to be added before your answer. You can add it and I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you.